# Trying to refactor code from a for to a map function and cannot figure it out

Tags: loops, refactoring, array.prototype.map

```
    const winningNums = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        winningNums.push(Math.round(Math.random()*100))
    }
    return winningNums
}
```

Above code I used a forLoop which I am more familiar with, but I have recently learned about the `.map()` and trying to refactor that loop using a `.map()` and keep failing

Any tips or suggestions?

I tried this but I have failed:

`const randomNums = winningNums.map(winningNums => Math.round(Math.random()*100));`

Comment: The map() method changes the elements of the array (and returns a new array), but your array is empty.

Comment: Thank you, i fixed it based on what you said that gave me a clue!